# Shouldn't preallocation of arrays in numpy be faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, malloc

I am confused why `test2` is not faster than `test1` in the following code:

```
import timeit

setup = """
import numpy as np
A = np.ones((220, 220, 220))
B = np.ones((220, 220, 220))

class store:
    def __init__(self):
        self.C = np.empty((220, 220, 220))
Z = store()
"""

test1 = """
C = A + B
"""

test2 = """
Z.C = A + B
"""

print timeit.timeit(test1, setup, number=1000)
print timeit.timeit(test2, setup, number=1000)
```

which gave me:
`40.9241290092
40.7675480843`

I thought because `Z.C` was preallocated memory, there would be less overhead every time I added `A+B` and needed a place to store it, i.e. less calls to `malloc` behind the scenes or something like that. What am I missing?

Comment: `Z.C = A + B` isn't updating the same array, it's a completely new assignment.

Comment: Oh, why isn't `Z.C` the same memory address every time, because it's a member of Z which has already been allocated?

Comment: `Z.C` doesn't pre-allocate anything, right now it's pointing to a numpy array and later it can point to a string. Once it points to a new object the old object will be garbage collected if there are no references to it anymore.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand, I suppose `Z.C` could be assigned something with completely different dimensions or something like that, so every assignment is just treated as a new one. I suppose you see what I'm after though, is there some equivalent of allocating the array only once and then updating the existing allocation?

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a good overview of how Python variables and assignment work (though be aware that arrays handle elements and slices differently from lists).

Comment: If you want to *actually* use a preallocated output array, that's `numpy.add(A, B, out=Z.C)`, though you didn't need to create `Z` just to hold the `C` array.

Comment: Awesome, this just doubled the speed for some of my modules. Thanks!

Comment: ^ I tested `Z.C[...] = A + B` in the above code and it gives the same approximate run time as `Z.C = A + B` i.e. does not benefit from the speedup given by `numpy.add(A, B, out=Z.C)`

Comment: Don't put too much effort into micromanaging the memory allocation.  There are usually more significant parts of the code.  Often we don't know when `numpy` is creating temporary buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Allocation is a fast operation, addition is more expensive:

```
In [7]: %timeit  np.empty((220, 220, 220))
1000 loops, best of 3: 472 µs per loop

In [8]: u= np.ones((220, 220, 220))

In [9]: %timeit  u+u
10 loops, best of 3: 73.5 ms per loop
```

So, even if you correctly update your array (`Z.C[:]= A+B`) you will not win a lot in your case (~0.5%).